# Jmeter : IIS server stops responding

Tags: iis, jmeter

I am learning jmeter to check perform of the web application.  This web application is hosted on IIS server and built in php. For testing we use windows 10 PC with 4GB RAM.

I am checking load testing with jmeter where I am sending 10 login request to IIS server with ramp-up periods 3 sec , IIS server stops responding and I have to restart IIS service. If I set ramp-up period 4 SEC then it is working fine.

I m expecting IIS should handle 10 request in 2 sec. For this what configuration should I change in IIS ?

Answer (score 1):

My expectation is that you're hitting [IIS concurrent connections](https://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/windows-8-iis-8-concurrent-requests-limit) limit:

[image]

Single JMeter virtual user can open up to 7 connections to the server when retrieving [embedded resources](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/web-testing-jmeter-how-properly-handle-embedded-resources-html-responses/) so I think you can only do some functional testing using JMeter, but not the load testing.

If you want to identify the limits of your application and conduct some load testing you should consider upgrading to [Windows Server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Server) operating system which doesn't have this limits.

Alternative solution is migrating from IIS to i.e. [Apache](https://httpd.apache.org/) which is [capable of hosting PHP applications](https://www.petefreitag.com/item/516.cfm), in this case you will have much more concurrent connections allowed

Comment: Just a minor issue. Apache on Windows client OS still suffers this limit, so in the last paragraph it should be better to say "Apache (except on Windows client OS)".

Comment: Lex Li is correct.  The problem isn't with IIS; the problem is that Microsoft deliberately "baked in" this limitation because they consider Windows 10 Pro a "client OS".  For this kind of "load testing", the OP really needs to use Windows Server.  Even Windows Server running on a VM will give more realistic results.